# how to click a text link (foreign language) using Selenium? (when the class in anchorstyle)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on one of the buttons (in blue), they are opening the same page when you click on them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj9VV.png

Its the inspect to the right linked text:

```
   <a id="ctl00_mp_lnkPresenceReproting" class="anchorStyle" onclick="RedirectQuickLinks('Attendance/calendarpage.aspx','5610207277369',2);">
                            דיווח ועדכון</a>
```

and this one for the left linked text (I manage to open the popmenu by clicking it with selenium so the problem is just the linked text)

```
   <a id="innerNavBarItem_47" onclick="navigationManager.navItemClicked(this, 'tabItem_9_3_SpanBackground');" navigateurl="Attendance/calendarpage.aspx" href="javascript:void(0);" title="דיווח ועדכון" tabindex="-1">דיווח ועדכון</a>
```

I tried to use ID. it finds the left linked text but doesn't click it. The right one, it doesn't even find and I get an error.
When I try to use xpath on both of them, the click is not working.

I cant use "find element by link text" because it doesn't recognise hebrew.

```
Nohehut = browser.find_element_by_id('tabItem_9_3_SpanBackground')
Nohehut.click()
DivuahvIdkun = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="innerNavBarItem_47"]') 
DivuahvIdkun.click()
```

here is the source page: https://hasteb.in/ugujosux.xml

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some scenarios, the locator 'id' changes dynamically , In one of your code, I see 'id' as 'innerNavBarItem_47' which might change in future.

For example, if a new item/element is introduced in your webpage and if that appears before your element, your element 'id' number might get pushed to **innerNavBarItem_48** from **innerNavBarItem_47**. So always go with the xpath or css locators if it looks the id of element is autogenerated dynamically.

Below code should solve your issue

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@navigateUrl,'calendarpage')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)
```

**note :** I have used javascriptexecutor above  to click on the element considering your statement in the question - "I tried to use ID. it finds the left linked text but doesn't click it."

We go for JavascriptExecutor when selenium click does not work.